# displaying table data via select list with php

Tags: php

I have a select list with the column names from my table. When the submit button is clicked, a table is shown with the column name, but instead of showing the data from the table it just repeats the value of the select list. so for instance if teamname is selected. it shows 'teamname' 4 times because i have 4 rows in my table, but i want it to show the actual teamname not the word 'teamname;.

i believe it has something to do with my variable $select and how i use it in my sql statment or how im define it as a variable?

Its using the value from the select list and not the value from the table column.

*note: Using the PDO method for this*.

**HTML**

```
        <form method='post' action='phpfiles/selectList.php'>
            <select name='select'>
                <option value='teamname' id='team'>teamname</option>
                <option value='city' id='city'>city</option>
                <option value='best' id='best'>bestplayer</option>
                <option value='year' id='year'>year</option>
                <option value='website' id='website'>website</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type='submit' id='selectSubmit' value='Submit Data'>
        </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    $select = $_POST['select'];

    echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
    echo "<tr><th>'$select'</th></tr>";

    class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
        function __construct($it) { 
            parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
        }

        function current() {
            return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
        }

        function beginChildren() { 
            echo "<tr>"; 
        } 

        function endChildren() { 
            echo "</tr>" . "\n";
        } 
    } 

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){  

        // server and database information
       $servername = "localhost";
       $username = "";
       $password = "";
       $dbname = "";
       $select = $_POST['select'];

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT '$select' FROM teams"); 
            $stmt->execute();

            // set the resulting array to associative
            $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
                echo $v;
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $conn = null;
        echo "</table>";
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `'` quotes:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT $select FROM teams");
```

Or better, use "`" to quote it:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `$select` FROM teams");
```

`'` marks it as a simple string to output for your sql query, not as a column name (what you want).